# trying to add to treeset but it will not add

Tags: java

```
public class UniquesDupes
{
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public UniquesDupes(String input)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] words = "abc cde fgh ijk".split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
    }


    public Set<String> getUniques()
    {
        Set<String> uniques = new TreeSet<String>();

        for(String a:list)
        {
            uniques.add(a);
        }

        return uniques;
    }
```

getuniques does not work it compiles and runs but it doesnt add to the tree set and i do not know why

Comment: How do you know it does not add to the tree? You haven't shared any code showing how you access the tree, nor any code and output showing the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

That assuming other things work fine,

You are creating another variable list in the method scope ,

change `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));`  to

```
this.list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
```

to refer to the private variable `list`

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
```

This line creates a new variable, *also* named `list`, which has nothing to do with your original `list` variable.

You want

```
list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
```

or even

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(words));
```